# No data return when performing a self join

Tags: c#, sql, linq, self-join

I have a table contain the payment records of agencies. I want to sum total payment of each agency into 2 columns, first is current day payment and second is the day before payment.

So I try the SQL like this.

```
select p1.UserName, p1.PaymentAmount, p2.PaymentAmount
from vw_Agency_Payment p1
join vw_Agency_Payment p2 on p1.UserName=p2.UserName
where p1.PaymentDate = '2014-08-07'
  and p2.PaymentDate = '2014-08-08'
```

It is successful and return the data.

But when I convert it to Linq like below:

```
var yesterday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
var tomorrow = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);

var agencyPayment = from y in db2.vw_Agency_Payment
                    join t in db2.vw_Agency_Payment on y.UserName equals t.UserName
                    where y.PaymentDate >= yesterday
                       && y.PaymentDate < DateTime.Today
                       && t.PaymentDate >= DateTime.Today
                       && t.PaymentDate < tomorrow
                    select new AgencyPaymentModel
                               {
                                   agencyUserCode = y.UserName,
                                   yesterdayPayment = y.PaymentAmount,
                                   todayPayment = t.PaymentAmount,
                                   growth = (t.PaymentAmount - y.PaymentAmount) / y.PaymentAmount * 100
                               };

return View(agencyPayment.OrderByDescending(c => c.growth).Take(100).ToList());
```

It return no data.
I don't know what make it wrong!?

Answer (score 1):

Why not the following code (taking the date part of datetime field)?

```
var yesterday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);

var agencyPayment = from y in db2.vw_Agency_Payment
                    join t in db2.vw_Agency_Payment on y.UserName equals t.UserName
                    where y.PaymentDate.Date = yesterday
                       && t.PaymentDate.Date = DateTime.Today
                    select new AgencyPaymentModel
                               {
                                   agencyUserCode = y.UserName,
                                   yesterdayPayment = y.PaymentAmount,
                                   todayPayment = t.PaymentAmount,
                                   growth = (t.PaymentAmount - y.PaymentAmount) / y.PaymentAmount * 100
                               };

return View(agencyPayment.OrderByDescending(c => c.growth).Take(100).ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 where y.PaymentDate >= yesterday
                   && y.PaymentDate < DateTime.Today
                   && t.PaymentDate >= DateTime.Today
                   && t.PaymentDate < tomorrow
```

> No result will satisfy this condition:
>
> from line 1-2, PaymentDate is limited to yesterday... intersect with line 3 will narrow down to nothing.
>
> Basically you need to draw a reasonable range.
>
> Plus, snippet 2 contains more logic than snippet 1, you should test them under same conditions.

Comment: Hi CodeFarmer,
The PaymentDate from line 1-2 is of Y and the rest is of T.

Comment: var yesterday may not has same format as y.PaymentDate, sometime date comparison will fail because of format inconsistance. Secondly, dont' do (t.PaymentAmount - y.PaymentAmount) / y.PaymentAmount * 100. Int value will round up if you are expecting double or higher precision.

Comment: All date field are datetime. All number field are decimal.